# How to get unread notifications with the help of Github Node Module?

Tags: node.js, npm, github-api

Is there any way to get unread notifications(issues, pull requests etc) with the help of Github node module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/github).

Comment: The GitHub Notifications API (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/) allows you to fetch notification data. Based on the docs for that package (http://mikedeboer.github.io/node-github and https://www.npmjs.com/package/github#implemented-github-apis), it doesn't look like the package provides support for the Notifications API. I was going to recommend that you open an issue on the package's repo, but I see that you've already done so (https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github/issues/265).

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way of getting notifications through Github node module. I wrote a node module for solving my problem. https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-notification